# Axios Post using React Native variable

Tags: php, react-native, axios

React Native newbie, trying to figure out why my react native variable isn't passing in my axios post request. This works:

```
    let lat = (location.latitude);
    let lon = (location.longitude);


    const loadMessages = async () => {


        let res = await axios.post('https://example.com/list.php?coords='+(lat)+','+(lon),  
        
        {
            latitude: 'foo'
        });
```

I get 'foo' in my php backend, and I'm also able to access coords from $_GET. But when I try to stick a variable in the post data, instead, it doesn't work. I'm trying:

```
    let body = { latitude: lat };
     //body= JSON.stringify(body);


    const loadMessages = async () => {

        let res = await axios.post('https://example.com/list.php?coords='+(lat)+','+(lon),  
        
        {
            body
        });
```

using, in my backend:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

I think the problem may be in the way I'm calling/trying to access the object on the PHP side. Please include how to refer access on PHP side if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using axios.get would be easier for you as your current payload does not require to use axios.post, you would access all the properties under $_GET on the PHP side, I have trouble seeing the problem without a working example

Comment: not for the instant case, but for when I need to post data instead, for various reasons like security, length, etc.